# Alternate proof of this identity for the generalized Harmonic number?

Tags: continued-fractions, harmonic-numbers

I discovered this identity starting with a continued fraction representation of the generalized harmonic number and using the alternating sum definition described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) (Theorem 3; Corollary 3).
$$H_{2k+1,r}=\cfrac{1}{1-\sum_{n=1}^k\left(\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{(2n)^r}+\cfrac{1}{(2n+1)^r}}{H_{2n-1,r}H_{2n+1,r}}\right)}$$
I was wondering if there is another way that we could prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum in the denominator can be written as

$$\sum_{n=1}^k \left(\cfrac{\cfrac{1}{(2n)^r}+\cfrac{1}{(2n+1)^r}}{H_{2n-1,r}H_{2n+1,r}}\right) \\ =       \sum_{n=1}^k \left(     \cfrac{    H_{2n+1,r} -H_{2n-1,r}   }         {H_{2n-1,r}H_{2n+1,r}}\right)  \\  =   \sum_{n=1}^k \left(     \frac {1}{H_{2n-1,r}} - \frac {1}{H_{2n+1,r}   }  \right)   \\ =    \left(     \frac {1}{H_{1,r}} - \frac {1}{H_{2k+1,r}   }  \right) $$ $$ = 1-   \frac {1}{H_{2k+1,r}   } $$

Substituting this in the initial equation reported by the OP, we directly get the trivial equation

$$H_{2k+1,r}=\cfrac{1}{1-  \left(1-   \frac {1}{H_{2k+1,r}   } \right)   } = \cfrac {1}{\frac {1}{H_{2k+1,r} }  } =H_{2k+1,r}  $$

Comment: Beautiful proof!  Definitely deserves more upvotes!